# Check the selected checkboxes on revisiting a page

Tags: jquery, html

I have pagination implemented in my grid using AJAX and as I move to next page only the grid gets refreshed. The idea is to let the user check the box next to each record or check the "checkall", which will check all the records. When I revisit the same page I want the check box for those selected records checked. 
  In order to accomplish this :  each time I select a record I am moving it into a `div` which is on the layout page. Now when I revisit a page I want to look into the `div` and grab the `ids` for that page and check the checkboxes for all the selected records on that page.

[HTML HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/XMLGw/18/)`H`

Thanks

Comment: If the page changes then you need to persist the data; sounds like the perfect job for session storage or local storage.

Comment: I am moving the selected records into a div which is in the layout page. and I am refreshing the page using AJAX

Comment: Well if you're refreshing the page with ajax then you're not refreshing the page at all! I think you should clarify your question.

Comment: You can just store the selected ids in an array in your layout page

Comment: Try using jQuery cookie plugin https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie to store the page ids